# Salesforce server speeds - deterministic or not?

Tags: email, performance

I am testing an email utility which I have written to automatically send some attachments to recipients based on some logic.

I am noticing that the speed with which the recipient receives the email varies from 2 - 6 minutes.

I am currently using the cs81 server. As per [Salesforce Trust](https://status.salesforce.com/status), the status for this server is fine.

Am I correct in saying that I cannot do anything to increase the speed with which recipients receive their emails and attachments, since the dependency is with the Salesforce server? I have noticed that there doesn't seem to be a correlation between lower attachment memory and quicker speed either - it just seems quite random in speed whether the attachment(s) in the email are <100kb or ~ 2.5MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the speed of the servers is not deterministic. Even in a closed system, there would be variance based on several factors, primarily system load. And when you have two different servers involved, both of which may have different levels of activity, they are not in an identical state every time they are called. This is just a fact of life in developing for the multi-tenant environment.

Take a simple example to see how variance can come into play:

```
Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    Boolean isZero = i == 0;
system.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - start);
```

This can vary noticeably in time consumed and doesn't even involve callouts, sending emails, or anything remotely complicated. I ran it just four times and got values anywhere from 36ms elapsed to 68ms elapsed.

Comment: Thanks v.much - I was sure it wasn't deterministic, but maybe this question helps others too.